# Oracle SQL Plus variable value assignment using CASE

Tags: sql

I want to set the V_PROFILE variable to a value determined by the value of the V_USERID variable in Oracle SQL Plus. Database version 12.1.0.2

The below code returns the correct answer but I need to set a variable instead of returning the literal answer.

```
def V_PROFILE=''
def V_USERID='USER_KCH'

select 
CASE substr('&V_USERID',1,1)
    WHEN 'U' THEN
          'USER_PROFILE'
    WHEN 'S' THEN
          'SERVICE_PROFILE'
    ELSE  'NO PROFILE'
END
from dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are doing this in SQLPLus, I believe you can do:

```
COLUMN column_name NEW_VALUE variable_name
```

In your case, you would need to add an alias for the selected column in the query, and do

```
COLUMN alias NEW_VALUE v_profile
```

(Hopefully I'm remembering the syntax correctly.)

Answer (score 0):

Oracle SQL Plus variable value assignment using CASE

The below code sets the V_PROFILE variable to a value determined by the value of the V_USERID variable in Oracle SQL Plus. 
Database version 12.1.0.2The below code sets

```
def V_PROFILE=''
def V_USERID='USER_KCH'
def V_USERID='SERVICE_KCH'
def V_USERID='OTHERVALUE'

COLUMN PROFILE NEW_VALUE V_PROFILE NOPRINT

select 
    CASE substr('&V_USERID',1,4)
       WHEN 'USER' THEN
            'USER_ACCOUNTS_PROF'
       WHEN 'SERV' THEN
            'SERVICE_ACCOUNTS_PROF'
       ELSE 'DEFAULT'
    END as profile
from dual;

DEFINE V_PROFILE       = "USER_ACCOUNTS_PROF" (CHAR)
DEFINE V_PROFILE       = "SERVICE_ACCOUNTS_PROF" (CHAR)
DEFINE V_PROFILE       = "DEFAULT" (CHAR)
```